# Postgresql: master-slave replication of 1 table

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave

Help me to chouse a simple (lightweight) solution to the master-slave replication of **one table** between two Postgresql databases. The table contains a large object.

Comment: good question (but hard to answer), +1. large object facility uses a shared system table, and postgres does not allow triggers on system catalog.

Comment: reportedly, [symmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/) can replicate large objects. worth testing... but is it lightweight? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) you'll find a very good overview of the replication tools for PostgreSQL. Please, take a look and hopefully you'll be able to pick one.

Otherwise, if you need something really lightweight, you can do it yourself. You'll need a trigger and a couple of functions, a [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html) module if you need almost immediate changes propagation, otherwise you can survive with `cron`.