# Architecture Challenge with 2 databases

Tags: database, architecture

How to handles two databases for a single rest app. I see that this is a cloud app concept but in cases that something gets deleted in DB1 and not DB2 how to handle this and make sure that both are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

First you need to consider **whether the DBs have the same schema and data**. in such case a master-slave, master-master replication will solve it.

In the case where the schema and data is similar in some tables an not in others, in that case you can use dblink to replicate just one table [Postgresql: master-slave replication of 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200830/postgresql-master-slave-replication-of-1-table)

most of the time such changes are made in the app level and if you really want to avoid dealing with 2 phase commit, you can have a queue and a service processing (retrying and recovering) the updates to both dbs

finally in the case where direct updates to the db (without passing through the app) are required to be supported, triggers and dblink is an opportunity.

Please explore these tools to get more ideas: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

EDIT: start here if you're lucky enough to have the same db/data https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-bdr-2ndquadrant/

Comment: Is there a way to avoid conflicts when no replication or other technics are used? in a rest service without a load-balancer? So at t1 access to db1 can happen and at t2 access at db2 occurs. I am sure that without any replication 2 phase commit, the design is pretty much handicapped and prone to corruption. A person in the team told me that having a rest-endpoint informing that the entry has been deleted would satisfy the condition.

Comment: can you elaborate more about your specific case? what kind of app is it?

Comment: I would simply say some CRUD app.

Comment: For a crud app, there is a way but it is hardcore as f*ck. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type

also you may check conflict resolution techniques as locking of objects (ala CVS), or automatically like (last change is kept), etc. still you will need to diff data very often

Comment: you can also do something like a merkle tree and send diffs of only what changed...